# how to solve: AWS codebuild always set secondary source repository to public?

Tags: terraform, aws-codebuild

I have the following codebuild

```
secondary_sources {
    source_identifier   = "AutomationSuite"
    type                = "BITBUCKET"
    location            = "https://<my repo>.git"
    git_clone_depth     = 1
    report_build_status = true
    insecure_ssl        = false
    git_submodules_config {
      fetch_submodules = true
    }

  }
```

After applying I always see in the AWS codebuild console[image]

How can I change this behaviour to repository in my bitbucket account?